# Let $M$, $N$ be manifolds of class $\mathcal{C}^r$ for $r \ge 1$. Show, that $M \times N$ is a manifold of class $\mathcal{C}^r$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

First of all: What does it mean that a manifold is of class $\mathcal{C}^r$? I find this kind of strange because we defined a manifold as a subspace, and not a function.

Should I just show that if any element from my manifolds $M$, $N$ is of class $\mathcal{C}^r$, then any element from the manifold $M \times N$ is of class $\mathcal{C}^r$, too? But this could only be the case if the elements from $M$ and $N$ are functions?

Anyways, would it be enough to show a diffeomorphism between $M$, $N$ and $M \times N$ which would be of class $\mathcal{C}^r$?

I'm honestly confused about all of this

Comment: It means that the transition functions of the manifold admit derivatives until order $r$

Comment: What are transition functions? Are those the functions $\phi : \: U \rightarrow V$ if I've got a map $(U, \phi)$ in the neighborhood of a point $x \in M$?

Comment: exactly, you have two charts (U, phi) and (V, psi) of a point p. A transition function is the composition psi\circ phi^-1 : R^n\to R^n

Comment: So isn't that exercise trivial then? I can't see how there should be something broken if we take $M \times N$? Let's say we've got $(U_1, \phi_1)$ for a point $x_m \in M$, and $(U_2, \phi_2)$ for $x_n \in N$. Here, $x_m$ and $x_n$ are arbitrary. Now if we want to find the map on point $(x_m, x_n) \in M \times N$, it's just $(U_1 \times U_2, \phi_3)$ where $\phi_3 : \: M \times N \ni (x,y) \rightarrow (\phi_1 (x), \phi_2 (y)) \in \mathcal{C}^r$?

Comment: exactly, it’s trivial 

Comment: The exercise is primarily meant to test your understanding of the basic definitions.